# Remove a combination of Number and . from a string in Excel

Tags: excel

I have the input "Nokia S40 Browser 2.2.0"  from this i want to remove version number. The output should be "Nokia S40 Browser". In other words i want to remove 2.2.0 from my input. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the version number is always the last part of the text then you can use

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

To get the last part and

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",100)),100)),"")
```

To remove the last part of the text.

[image: Screenshot]

Or you could use a RegEx to remove the version numbers

```
Function remomveVers(Myrange As Range) As String
    'Dim regEx As New regEx
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim strOutput As String


    strPattern = "([0-9]{1,2}[.][0-9]{1,2}[.][0-9]{1,2})|([0-9]{1,2}[.][0-9]{1,2})"

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Myrange.Value
        strReplace = ""

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.test(strInput) Then
            remomveVers = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
        Else
            remomveVers = "Not matched"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

You can use this function on your sheet (see screenshot below)

[image: Secreenshot RegEx]

Comment: If you change both `100`'s to `LEN(A1)`, it will never fail due to an exceedingly long text string in A1.

Comment: No the above code is not generating half output. I tried evaluating the formula too

Comment: i've added a screenshot of the formula working but as I said in my answer it will only work if the version number you want to remove is at the end of the text.

Comment: I've added a RegEx function that can remove #.#.# from anywhere in the text.  I'm no RegEx expert so the string pattern could most likely be improved but it does work.

Comment: Gordon can you please check for following inputs Adobe AIR (Unknown Version), 360 Secure Browser, Android Browser, Dolphin, Google Chrome (GoogleTV), Internet Explorer Mobile, Microsoft Internet Explorer 5.23 (Macintosh), Microsoft MSN Explorer, Mobile NetFront, Motorola MIB, Mozilla Firefox 3.0 beta, NetFront, Netscape Navigator 4.0 beta 3, Safari 3.0 (iPhone). Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I've tested some of those and updated the string pattern so that it removes #.#.# or #.#. S o it will remove 3.0 or 5.23.